# What if gravity switched off for an instant?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I had this thought bothering me for a while. What if gravity suddenly switched off.what would happen to us?would we fly off radially outward.Or would we fly off in a tangential path.or would nothing happen.Could someone please throw some light on this.thanks:)

Comment: The answer to these non-real physics questions are almost always *extremely* dependent on the exact details of what you mean by "gravity switching off."  For one example of those details, consider that every object has some gravitational potential energy.  Is that energy conserved? Does it vanish from the universe?  If it vanishes, there's some really strange quirks that show up due to Nother's theorem.  If it doesn't vanish, where does the energy go?

Comment: You can turn this into a more mainstream question by creating a scenario you are interested in, and trying to solve the equations of motion.  For example, if you have a spinning sphere (no gravity), and an object near the surface of the sphere moving at the same angular rate as the sphere, you can calculate what happens after that.

Comment: I VTC, due to my personal opinion that these extreme "what if", physically extremely unlikely questions  are nearly always too broad to answer. No offence intended to the OP, but it ain't going to happen.

Comment: Asking "what happens if gravity switched off?" is hypothetical (not going to happen) and potentially very broad.  However,  you seem to be asking  if an object is moving in a circle will fly off radially or tangentially if the centripetal force is suddenly "switched off". This could realistically happen if a string broke or someone riding on a roundabout let go. So you should think about altering the wording of your question.

Comment: Aww, I was working on a great answer! I was just about to describe the Sun exploding. We need a WhatIf.SE.

Comment: @Schwern  we already have one :(   but it is genuinely not a bad idea

Comment: @CountTo10 We have one? Do you mean [Worldbuilding.SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/)? I guess it's the closest equivalent.

Comment: @Schwern yeah, worldbuilding, but I have to say they refused to take a few posts I suggested, too far out even for them. There is a lot of genuine curiosity among non science types,  after the LHC, especially,I got bombarded with neighbors/ friends simply wanting to know more, (up to a point:).....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enterprising† teenagers have experimentally verified the theoretical results for you.

In their experimental setup, tangential and radial trajectories require careful study to differentiate. They simulated a sudden cessation of  centripetal force by the expedient of disconnecting the experimenter from the apparatus.

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HKMKfHAChZU).

For the theoretical case, just consider what direction‡ you are travelling in as you sit at your computer. Tangential or Radial?

---

† I.e. oiks.
‡ With respect to, say, an observer in space travelling mid-way between Earth and Sun